# Specific regex pattern matching Python

Tags: python, regex, string

**Issue**
I got a problem and unfortunately I'm not *too* familiar with regex just yet but I'm trying to solve an issue I have with automatically processing text. In reality the issue is a tiny bit more complex than the example I'm going to give below but that's mainly to simplify it as much as possible as the issue lies with my regex abilities.

Say we have a string that contains two different types of patterns. In this case **AA** and **BB** and they are at random locations in the string. These patterns could be present zero or more times in complete random order.

For example:
`"Hello, this AAis just a BB test string. I'm AA here to test BB the regex."`

What I want to do is search and replace the word "test" with the word "fix" based on the following two rules:

1. If only **AA** patterns are found before "test", then "test" won't be replaced.
2. If only **BB** patterns are found before "test", then "test" is replaced with "fix".
3. If 1 or more **AA** and 1 or more **BB** are present before "test", then of these multiple patterns the BB pattern must come last. If this is the case, "test" is replaced with "fix".
4. If none of the patterns are found then "test" is always replaced with "fix".

---

**Example:**
So in the above example the word "test" shows up twice.
The first part is: `"Hello, this AAis just a BB test"`
Rule number 3 applies and passes. Both patterns are found before the "test" and it ends with BB.

The second part is: `Hello, this AAis just a BB test string. I'm AA here to test"`
Here rule number 3 applies but does not pass.

The final result being:
`"Hello, this AAis just a BB fix string. I'm AA here to test BB the regex."`

---

**Different solution:**
Now, there are other ways to achieve this. For example, count how many times "test" is in a string and do some for loop where I keep track which pattern came last (if they exist) until I find "test" and take action based on which one came last. Repeat this process until all cases of "test" are found but this feels really inefficient.

---

**My attempt at a regex solution**
Initially, my issue was that everything was greedy. So `[AA]*.*[BB]*.[^AA]+test` resulted in everything until the last 'test' in the string when I just wanted the match up until the first "test" match and slowly iterate until I got to the last one.

So, I modified it to: `[AA]*?.*[BB]+?[^AA]*?test?`
Based on regex documentation appending a `?` makes it non-greedy.
This is almost what I want, rule 2 and 3 are covered but this won't work for rule 1. So I'm not quite sure how to fix this regex pattern.

Also, how would I iterate my regex pattern over the entire string AND use re.sub to replace the words when needed?

---

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what *AA* and *BB* would be? Are they just particular strings or are they regexs themselves?

Comment: I am afraid there are 2 questions in one: 1) split into sentences, 2) replace test after the last BB. Right?

Comment: What happens when neither pattern is present?

Comment: @skyler Only AA is a regex, BB is just a predefined string. AA is of the format ^xyz where x, y and z are all integers. So that translates to a regex pattern that looks like this: \^\d{3}

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, when you put it like that that is the case.

Comment: What if you have "BB test AA test BB test" all as one sentence?

Comment: `"BB test"` would result in rule 2 and thus it would be replaced.  
`"BB test AA test"` would match rule 3 but not pass as it does not end with BB.  
`"BB test AA test BB test"` would match rule 3 and passes as well as it ends with BB and thus it would be replaced.  

Resulting in `"BB fix AA test BB fix"`

Comment: Let me suggest [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/sR4aX3/1) for cases where you want to test 1 string. Does it work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This does seem to work nicely though it seems I forgot to add a rule, which I added just now. All three of the rules are (before I added #4) work perfect. If I'm honest, I'm having a tough time understanding the regex you wrote, haha. I'd love to understand what it means exactly. Seems you've used groups.

Comment: In Python, it will look untidy, but try [`(^(?:(?!BB|AA).)*|BB(?:(?!BB|AA).)*)test`](https://regex101.com/r/sR4aX3/2) to replace with `\1fix`. I doubt it is a job for one regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think trying to build a single regular expression to do everything is going to be a fruitful approach. Instead, let's use multiple regular expressions and a little programming to solve the problem:

```
def replace_test(string):
    aa_locs = [(m.start(), "aa") for m in re.finditer(AA, string)]
    bb_locs = [(m.start(),  "bb") for m in re.finditer(BB, string)]
    merged = sorted(aa_locs + bb_locs + [len(string), "end"])
    start = 0
    result = ""
    replacing = False
    for end, pattern_type in merged:
        if replacing:
             result += string[start:end].replace("test", "fix")
        else:
             result += string[start:end]
        if pattern_type == "bb":
             replacing = True
        start = end
    return result
```

It is a bit complex and could probably be cleaned up, but let me explain what this code does. First, we want to make a list of every time the state can change in order to break the string into regions where we will be replacing the word "test" and regions where we do not. We get a list of each time AA is found and a list of each time BB is found. We store these as tuples `(index, pattern)`. That way we know where there is a possible state change. After that I merged these into a singled list. I also added a sentinel value that we will need to make sure we actually copy the whole string later on.

We know the initial state is not to replace and we start at the beginning of the string. In each iteration we take a portion of the string and add it to the result. After doing this we update the state based on what pattern we have just matched "aa" or "bb".

Comment: I've done a modified version of this one and it seems to do the trick quite nicely.
Thank you for your suggestions and help guys! Much appreciated!